# How to convert strings from python3.6 to older version?

Tags: python, string

I use python3.6 , but for this work, I need to use an older version of Python.

I would like to convert this line (python3.6) to an older version if it is possible :

```
for uniref in [f">{chunk.rstrip()}" 
   for chunk in data.split(">")]:
```

I tried

```
for uniref in [">{chunk.rstrip()}" 
    for chunk in data.split(">").format(chunk.rstrip())]:
```

but I got back this error message `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'format'`

Comment: Use `str.format`
? --> `for uniref in [">{}".format(chunk.rstrip()) for chunk in data.split(">")]:`

Comment: i think pycharm provide this functionality to change string format to python format

Comment: Start by fixing the formatting of code, I have done some fixing, you can finish the rest

Comment: your error occurs because split() returns a list and you're trying to use string method .format on a list.

Comment: I used the `str.format` as Rakesh advised me, and it works. Thanks